# Gradient text over multiple navigation elements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a navigation bar with a gradient that continues over all the items, such as [Gradient Navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JS4KR.png)

I've come some way with using `background-clip: text;` but this causes problems with `font-awesome` and I don't know how to set the top/bottom borders to follow the gradient with the text.

The other way I tried it with a gradient background on the parent element and using mix-blend-mode, but this causes an occasional glitch between the items. [Gradient glitch with mix-blend-mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwl2J.png)

My question is, **what's the best way to achieve such gradient navigation?**

Here's the code (`background-clip: text;`)

```css
body {
  background: #161616;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff0066, #2850ff);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}

.menu li {
  display: table-cell;
}

.menu li a {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  padding: 32px 10px 30px 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
}

i.fa {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="header">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-search fa"></i>Search</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**And with mix-blend-mode:**

```css
body {
  background: #161616;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
}

.menu {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff0066, #2850ff);
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
  display: table-cell;
}

.menu li a {
  color: #000000;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 80px;
  display: inline;
  padding: 33px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  color: #000000;
  padding: 30px 10px;
}

i.fa {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="header">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-search fa"></i>Search</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost good with your first method. You need to make the icon `display:inline` to override the `inline-block` set by Font Awesome that prevent the background trick from working.

For the line color you can consider `border-image` with the same gradient applied to the same element. The trick is to apply negative margin on the `li` to overlap that gradient and on hover you reset the margin to show it.

```css
body {
  background: #161616;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  height: 80px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.menu {
  height: 100%;
  display:flex;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
  border-image-source:linear-gradient(90deg, #ff0066, #2850ff);
  border-image-slice:2 0;
  border-top:2px solid;
  border-bottom:2px solid;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff0066, #2850ff);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  display:flex;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin:-2px 0;
  border-top:2px solid white;
  border-bottom:2px solid white;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.menu li a {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li:hover {
  margin:0 0;
}

i.fa {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="header">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-search fa"></i>Search</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above doesn't work on Safari so you can try the following:

```css
body {
  background: #161616;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  height: 80px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.menu {
  height: 100%;
  display:flex;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
  border-image-source:linear-gradient(90deg, #ff0066, #2850ff);
  border-image-slice:2 0;
  border-top:2px solid;
  border-bottom:2px solid;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff0066, #2850ff);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
li {
  height:calc(100% - 4px);
  float:left;
  margin:2px 0;
  outline:4px solid #fff;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.menu li a {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height:75px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li:hover {
  outline:0px solid #fff;
}

i.fa {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="header">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-search fa"></i>Search</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense actually. This doesn't solve the issue with the top/bottom border having the same color as the text though?

Comment: @RobertN wait, I missunderstand that requirement, will update

Comment: Alif - Thanks but now it shows only the borders, the text is is now not showing?

Comment: @ Temani Alif - Good point. Safari. I just tried it on Firefox and Chrome and that works beautifully.

Comment: @RobertN the only browser where I cannot test ... can you try to remove the display:flex from `li` and see if it works ? don't care about the text moving on the top. Let's try to identify the bug so I can do it differently

Comment: Nope, that made no difference.

Comment: @RobertN remove also the display:flex from ul. Keep both removed and test

Comment: That makes it text reappear below each other: https://imgur.com/lA6elhR
(I made the header taller so it would all fit and it's easier to see the effect.)

Comment: @RobertN this not an issue, I simply wanted to know the culprit and it's display:flex. I will try to update my asnwer without using display:flex

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go ahead with second one as it is able to satisfy your usecase. For the issue of line between the items, you can change the ul to flex and remove the style of table cell on list items.

```css
body {
  background: #161616;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
}

.menu {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff0066, #2850ff);
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  display:flex;
}

   

.menu li a {
  color: #000000;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 80px;
  display: inline;
  padding: 33px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  color: #000000;
  padding: 30px 10px;
}

i.fa {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="header">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-search fa"></i>Search</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but that still shows the line between the items for me?

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible by using background-clip: text, and for font awesome icon issue you need to use font awesome icon by Unicode.

Please take a look at the updated snippet

```css
body {
  background: #161616;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ff0066, #2850ff);  
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}

.menu li {
  display: table-cell;
}

.menu li a {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
/*   -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; */
  color: transparent;
  padding: 32px 10px 30px 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.menu li a span {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
}
.menu li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
}

i.fa {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="header">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>&#xf002;</span> Search</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```